# Trying to wrap my head around Monotouch, storyboards and iPad split view apps?

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

Since about two weeks I've been trying to get a hang of MonoTouch. My objective is to develop a simple iPad application using the master/detail split view template, as provided by the Xcode interface / storyboard builder.

Although I've learned quite a lot, I just can't wrap my head around getting the split view to work. I'm able to "draw" the interface but then I get stuck.

I've worked though numerous online examples (mainly Objective-C based ones, as there are little MonoTouch based examples available). Many tutorials are old (based on Interface Builder and Xcode 3) and many seem to do random parts of the interface creation in code. For a newbie (not to programming, just to iOS development) it's quite a hard to thing to get a grasp on.

My objective is to make a simple app with the split view controller; in the master I want like 5 (static) cells. Tapping on a cell will give me the contents of a specific view controller (on the detail view). And that's it. Nothing more. I'm aware of MT.dialog, but I prefer to make use of native iOS stuff.

Any clues would be awesome.. tutorials, books, example apps.. whatever.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as learning how to use Storyboards, I would recommend using this tutorial provided on the Xamarin MonoTouch Documents website: [Introduction to Storyboards](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/User_Interface/Introduction_to_Storyboards)

When working with your cells, you are going to want to populate the UITableView with cells using a subclassed UITableViewSource class that you will override various methods to provide implementation with (Such as GetCell, RowSelected, HeightForRow, etc). When each cell is tapped, you will want to use the RowSelected() method of UITableViewSource class that you have subclassed. You will then want to figure out exactly which string was selected, pass this to your detail view's constructor, and decide how to display the detail screen from that data!

There are plenty of examples of this attached to the [Working with Tables and Cells](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/User_Interface/Tables) document on the Xamarin website (and they do a much better job explaining the process)!